# How to extract array index?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get index name from alike array

```
Array
(
    [mkpp] => 40
)
```

Index names vary in my case. So how can I always get what lies inside of `[$x]` ?

Comment: So $x in this example would be the string `mkpp`? In which case `$yourArray[$x]`.

Comment: There are several functions ex: [getting all the keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) , checking with `isset()` if the key exists, could you give a scenario with this?

Comment: Correct. I need this string value

Comment: @ka_lin `isset()` or [`array_key_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: I found out the function I need. It's `key(). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get string from array is `key()` function

Comment: You need to call this in a loop to get all the keys. `array_keys()` is simpler.

Comment: I always have one item in my array

Comment: Why do you make an array with one element and a varying key? What's the point of the key if it's not known?

Answer (score 0):

its simple,take a look at

```
$Array = array("first"=>1,"second"=>2)
foreach ($Array as $key => $value){
    echo "if you need key:". $key . "\n and value is: ".$value;
}
```

enjoy it :)